# How to read individual layers' weight & bias values from ONNX model?

Tags: protocol-buffers, onnx

How to get weight/bias matrix values from ONNX model, I can currently get the inputs, Kernel size, stride and pad values from `model.onnx`. I load the model and then read the graph nodes to get the same:

```
import onnx
m = onnx.load('model.onnx')
print(m.graph.node)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting an issue on official git repo, I got the answer to the question. We can access the weight values from initializers in `m.graph`.

```
weights = m.graph.initializer
```

To get the weight matrix, you need to use `numpy_helper` from **onnx**.

```
from onnx import numpy_helper
w1 = numpy_helper.to_array(weights[0])
```

Comment: I am still figuring out on how to convert the raw data into weight matrix.

Answer (score 6):

```
from onnx import numpy_helper
MODEL_PATH = "....../resnet50"
_model = onnx.load(MODEL_PATH + "/model.onnx")
INTIALIZERS=_model.graph.initializer
Weight=[]
for initializer in INTIALIZERS:
    W= numpy_helper.to_array(initializer)
    Weight.append(W)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: _model.graph.initializer will give list of all initializer of model likewise weight and bias.

Comment: How can we achieve this in C++?

Comment: in c++, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317076/11998382 `for (auto& tensor : graph.initializer())
        auto& bytes_as_string = tensor.raw_data()`

Answer (score 3):

The following code helps you to create a state dictionary from onnx model.

```
import onnx
from onnx import numpy_helper
onnx_model   = onnx.load("model.onnx")
INTIALIZERS  = onnx_model.graph.initializer
onnx_weights = {}
for initializer in INTIALIZERS:
    W = numpy_helper.to_array(initializer)
    onnx_weights[initializer.name] = W
```

Comment: `onnx_weights = {i.name: numpy_helper.to_array(i) for i in onnx_model.graph.initalizer}`